# How can I run a python program with cooperation of a web server?

Tags: python, django, web, webserver

I want to launch a program from a local pc and connect it to a web server for some database operations such as creating a new user, creating a user list, listing all users who accessed the web server earlier. But I don't have information how to do it. I think Django can help me out in somewhere but I'm not sure.

In addition, I want it secure and hidden way. Like spotify's servers those provide local application and stream locally with no foot step.

How can I do it, with which technologies or modules or methods?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have a look at the `flask` library.  This can run your web's backend, as well as creating the web UI.  [Here are the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).  Additionally, have a think about using a [RasPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) as your web server.  You can also use [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) for the database.  Fun project.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am looking the docs which you provided and RasPi right now. But something about Flask is not what I am looking for and I forgot the specify it in the question: I want the connect the web server in a secure and concealed way. Like spotify reaching the songs hidden way and streaming them in your local PC or smartphone. Maybe I am missing something about the way you said. Can you say anything about this situation? (And I will edit my question in this way)

Comment: Yes, just put the database and flask (web services) on a remote PC (RasPi for example), the user will only interact with the web browser not having visibility of what’s going on the in background.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Last mini question: Can Django be used instead of Flask for a project like this?

Comment: No worries, hope it’s fun for you. Sorry, I only have experience with Flask.  I don’t know.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. Have a good day and be safe...

Comment: Very kind of you, thank you.  You too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a fun project, here are some tools we've used in the past to do something similar:

#### Tech Stack:

- Python
- [`flask`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) library (web service and UI)
- [MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp) (database)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) (as a web/database server - have a Pi for each if you like)

#### Hide it Away:

If you want to 'hide' the toolset from the user, simply setup the web server and database on a remote PC (RasPi for example - or two Pis, web server and database server).  Then, the user will interact with the web UI and not have visibility of what's going on in the background.

#### Additional Reading:

If you're interested in web service stacks, have a look through this [LAMP Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29).  It breaks down and illustrates the concepts you're after very nicely.  A primary different is that you'll be using Flask, rather than Apache.

Hope this helps!